# Failure sending mail. When trying to send email multiple times

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, quartz.net, smtpclient, mailmessage

I am trying to send email using `SmtpClient` and `MailMessage`. I am trying to send email 35 times atleast and out of which 8 are sent and rest 26 shows the following exception:

```
Failure sending mail.
System
System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 74.208.5.2:25
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6)
at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
at \Schedulers\ConsumptionAlertJob.cs:line 90
```

My code is as follows:

```
var fromAddress= new MailAddress("xxxxxxx@xxxx.com", "Info");
const string fromPassword = "xxxxxxxx";
const string subject = "test";
string body = "test body";
var smtp = new SmtpClient
{
    Host="smtp.xxxxx.com",
    Port = 25,
    EnableSsl = true,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredentail(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
};

using (MailMessage message= new MailMessage()
{
    Subject=subject,
    Body=body
})
{
    message.To.Add("xxxxxxxx@gmail.com");
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

First thing that I thought was either port 25 is blocked but as it is sending 1/3rd of emails and giving exception on rest of 2/3rd this might not be the case. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

One thing worth mentioning is that all emails are sent when i run in Console Application. I get issue only when i try to run it in my web application project ASP.net MVC and job is executed in Quartz.net.

Regards

Comment: What code is at ´\Schedulers\ConsumptionAlertJob.cs:line 90´ ?

Comment: @AsheraH `smtp.Send(message);` is the line 90

Comment: If the emails are sent as separate jobs, can you try setting DisallowConcurrentExecution to see if the emails get sent correctly.Perhaps there is a limit on number of concurrent connections that the webserver can open, or perhaps the limit is on the mail server  side.